# How to select data from a table with a condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table just like following,

```
ID    |   dataCol
------------------
1          text1
2          text2
3          text3
```

I want to select all the data in above table with a condition such that if any row dataCol value is equal to 'text2' it should print as 'text4'.

my pseudo code is follows,

```
  select ID, (
if dataCol is equal to 'text2' 
then
 print 'text4'
 else
 dataCol
) from table1;
```

final out put should be like,

```
ID    |   dataCol
------------------
1          text1
2          text4
3          text3
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you do research?

Comment: Use a `case` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE datacol
       WHEN 'text2'
       THEN 'text4'
       ELSE datacol
       END
FROM   table1
```

or

```
SELECT ID,
       DECODE(
         datacol, -- input value
         'text2', -- first match
         'text4', -- output if matches first match
         datacol  -- default output
       )
FROM   table1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Id, case when dataCol='text2' then cast('text4' as nvarchar2(200)) 
else cast(dataCol as nvarchar2(200)) end dcol
from yourTable t
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
select ID, IF(dataCol = 'text2','text4',dataCol) as dataCol from table1
```

Comment: `IF` is a MySQL function and is not available in Oracle.

Comment: Above query is only for mysql.

Comment: And the above question is only for Oracle (not MySQL).